# Google map inside Divi Tab module

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I'm trying to load additional maps inside the Tab module that comes with the Divi wordpress theme.

Here's the page http://dev.klmsoccer.com/practice-schedules/
If you open the second tab - the map won't load there.

So the goal is to reinitialize or resize the map on click event.
The problem is that I've tried different selectors and code examples and nothing works.

The latest code I've tried was:

```
 ( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready( function(){

        $('.et_pb_tabs_controls > li.et_pb_tab_1').on('click', function () {

            var timeoutID = window.setTimeout( function(){
                    initialize();
            }, 600 );
        });
    });
})( jQuery );
```

PS. I know this has already been discussed few times but it doesn't seem to work for me with Divi. I'm a bit noob in js, so sorry if that's something stupid like wrong selector.

Comment: your tabs dont work at all and where is the `initialize()` function add along with the rest of your code .

Comment: the 3rd and 4th are just text now, but the map in the 2nd one doesnt work.
initialize() is there, i've just removed the timeout function.

Comment: i am saying that you should add that function here in your post so that we can look into that too

Comment: just posted an answer for you @Alex

Comment: i saw that you removed the errors i specified and the map is working now :)

Comment: well I thought initialize() should pick the original function invoked by the divi, but now it seems I need to do it myself. So i will go and read more about.

Comment: it is loading the map now , at least for me see the answer below with the image updated in the end

Comment: it now shows 'initialize is not defined' so I need to redeclare it manually somehow. Apparently it's easier just to give up on the maps in tabs.

Comment: hey , can you mark the answer as correct if it helped you solv the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your page, you are not closing the `</script>` tag properly. The same code block has a missing `>` from the `</script>` tag, it must be breaking your code. look here in the image below.

[image]

**EDIT**

And then after this one you have another same mistake at the point where you are calling the function `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` you must fix these errors in order to make sure there is really some conflict of the libraries you are using along with the `googlemaps`

see another image below

[image]

Map after fix

[image]

Comment: thanks for that, but the map on the 2nd tab still doesn't load.

Comment: I still see it like [this](https://imgur.com/a/G55E1) if I dont open it in full or try to resize.

Comment: that is strange.. which browser you are using i am on chrome

Comment: chrome as well, 62.0.3202.94